# Making a component that renders a different image based on a given prop

Tags: html, reactjs

Hello there I'm trying to make a component in which I can specify a different image every-time I create it but when I run the projet it sys Error: Cannot find module '../images/YS_icon.png'
[image]

Comment: i think this is your path issue. Give proper path it will resolve.

Comment: require doesn't work with dynamic paths